# Clicking link to WP site a second time causes blank page

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on re-developing an existing WordPress site. The site is hosted on Azure and is currently up to date @ v4.9.5.

Before i can even get started working on the site, i noticed a strange issue where if you click a link to the site twice in a row, the second time the site returns as a blank page with no resources loaded and no errors.

I've turned wp_debug on and error_reporting and the screen is completely blank. All plugins up to date, and i've deactivated all of them and switched to a standard theme and no change.

Not sure where to go from here, any help is greatly appreciated.

The site is located [here](http://technicallycreative.com).

**Resolved** in the last comment. Azure was throwing a server error which went un-noticed. Converting the page back to an ASP based page solved the issue.

Comment: "... if you click a link to the site twice in a row, the second time the site returns as a blank page (...)" What do you mean? Like a double-click? If so, is it a specific link that's causing this behavior?

Comment: It's a link for any page on the site. Take the one i provided. If you open the link in two new separate tabs, the second one opened will be a blank page.

Comment: That URL loads perfectly fine for me, even if I check the site on two browser tabs. Try [enabling WP's debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging) and check its contents after the page fails to load.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I opened the given link twice in a row in two different tabs and they both loaded just fine. Have you tried using a different browser? Or incognito mode or something? Or try clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, incognito, safari, opera, edge and cleared my cache. If i click and open that link in a new tab twice, the second one is completely blank.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your system, @DLzer...however I've also loaded your website across multiple browsers, loading the same URL numerous times. Seems like the issue is likely on your end. The website loads fine every time, with some errors (which I would recommend fixing).

Your errors are:

1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - oswald.light-webfont.woff2
2) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - fontawesome-webfont.woff2

Comment: For some reason, switching the PHP Page Template to an ASP page stopped the query string issues from happening.